# fullcalendar click on event could return timeslot which lays under it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Every event hovers some number of time slots. If I click on event I would like to get information about clicked event and timeslot which lays under it. From time slot I need at least information about time (date can take from event)

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: How are you storing the events? The events themselves should have information about their date and time

Comment: I need a time slot (I set length to 30 mins). Event starts at 9am finishes at 5pm, if I click on it I would like to take a time slot which lays under it (horizontal lines on calendar).